# Can new users still edit their own posts if links & images were added?

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks, new-users, question-restrictions

With my 2000+ Reputation, I often fix links and images around. e.g, I may change:

> see my bug at https:// i.stack.imgur .com/ foobar.png
>    (sorry, can't post images yet, not enough rep)

to:

> see my bug below
>   ![my bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foobar.png)

(with edit description "*inlining/embedding image*")

But I'm a bit worried that by doing this I may be preventing further/subsequent edits to the post by the owner of the post if he/she is only at 1-9 or 101-109 reputation (association bonus), according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user limitations:

> New users cannot:
>
> - post more than eight hyperlinks at a time, either in a post or their user profile

I'm not even sure if the limit of 8 hyperlinks is including images or if images have a separate count limit.

**Should I be careful and avoid inlining images or fixing links for users with less than 10 (110 with association) reputation?**

Bonus question: if new users are effectively locked from editing once someone raises the hyperlinks/images count above a certain threshold, is there a SEDE query to find posts owned by new users with too many links/images?

Comment: Well, they'll have to remove those links first. The system does not check who added them, just performs a check when the post is being submitted.

Comment: Users with the association bonus can always post images. I tested by creating an account on Ask Ubuntu. I got the association bonus and it allowed me to post images (but my 1 reputation sock puppet wasn't allowed to). The help center mentions the association bonus not counting, but that's only about answering protected questions, it has nothing to do with posting images.

Answer (score 1):

You can always edit your own posts *at any point of time*.

You *should* be doing any necessary fixes - both to links and images, and if they don't get the single upvote (the reputation *does* take into account association reputation, which is part of the point) - they can use the usual workarounds like lightly mangled URLs, or just get the upvotes they need.

Images and links are seen the same way, so it's a total. It's better to *fix* things, and let the new user see how it's done, rather than sit back "just in case"

Comment: Feels like not answer. The question is about the worry that new users can't even submit the same content vanilla after someone else raised the link count over the threshold.

Comment: But that worry shouldn't stop necessary edits - and the 'partial link' trick still works.